# Sentence Meaning using "have always been"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> My parents and teachers have always been supportive and have encouraged me

What is exact meaning of above sentence

if current month is September

1. They have been supportive from January till September
2. Thay have been supportive from January to September and in future also remain   supportive.
4. They were always supportive.
5. Or They have supported in past

Comment: Well, the first two make no sense, because verb tense has absolutely nothing to do with the arbitrary fact that some people start their year in January. So any time-frame from January is not a correct answer. Option three is also not valid, as it is not there. Only two left. Which one do _you_ think it is, and why?

Answer (score 2):

> My parents and teachers have always been supportive and encouraged me.

The time frame is from the current time (they are still doing so at the present time), and also into the past (but only you can say how long that has been, based on your experience).

Future actions are not implied at all. Also, repeating *have* in your example is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

It's a present perfect tence. something happened in the past and still continue in the present and can go to the future. So it's the choice 2. Pretty sure

Comment: Incorrect.  As was stated in a comment, the first two choices make no sense.